# A Geometric Problem: Looking for the Correct Interval

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I'm sorry I don't have enough reputation to upload an image, but my problem is well described by it (Please see). [The Geometric Model](https://ibb.co/gGDQ9k)

Definitions:

- $\phi_1^{(0)}$ is $\angle \text{A}_1\text{UH}$
- $\phi_2^{(0)}$ is $\angle \text{A}_2\text{UH}$
- $\phi_1^{(i)}$ is $\angle \text{A}_1\text{UH'}$
- $\phi_2^{(i)}$ is $\angle \text{A}_2\text{UH'}$
- $\theta_i$ is $\angle \text{HUH'}$

Let $0 \leq \theta \leq \pi/2$. Originally I have angles $\phi_1^{(0)}$ and $\phi_2^{(0)}$ when $\theta = 0$. Then, the point H starts moving to H' such that $\angle \text{UHH'} = \pi/2$ and $\angle \text{HUH'} = \theta_i$. Assume that we know all the locations of all points, i.e., U, $\text{A}_1$, $\text{A}_2$, H, and H'. (Or, equivalently we know all lengths defined by between those two points.)

Question: I am looking for following interval: $\theta^* = \{\theta_i| \cos\left(\phi_1^{(i)}\right) < \cos\left(\phi_2^{(i)}\right),  \forall 0 \leq \theta_i \leq \pi/2 \}$.

My first attempt is that using the law of cosine, but I'm stuck since I think I need more variables to solve it. I'm very clueless. So, I'd appreciate any hint.

Comment: As the point $H$ is the one that moves, angles $\phi_1^{(i)}$ and $\phi_2^{(i)}$ are independent from the angle $\theta_i$. Are you sure, that your definitions are right?

Comment: I think they are right because as $\theta_i$ increases the angle $\phi_1^{(i)}$ increases as well.

Comment: If the angle $\phi_1^{(i)}$ is determined by three stationary points, $\theta_i$ have no influence on it.